# How to get SD Card Size in framework?

Tags: android, frameworks

Refer to Google's code at 'DeviceStorageMonitorService.java', I want to create an implementation similar to Google to monitor the size of SD cards, but no matter how I handle it, the SD card size obtained is always 0.

```
@WorkerThread
private void checkExternal() {
    final StorageManager storage = getContext().getSystemService(StorageManager.class);
    StorageVolume[] list = storage.getVolumeList();
    boolean exist = false;
    StorageVolume storageVolume = null;
    for (StorageVolume volume : list) {
        String path = volume.getPath();
        boolean removable = volume.isRemovable();
        String vlState = volume.getState();
        if (removable && vlState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            exist = true;
            storageVolume = volume;
        }
    }
    if (!exist) {
        Slog.d(TAG, "sdcard don't exist.");
        return;
    }
    // updateExtraNotifications();
    Slog.d(TAG, "updateExtraNotifications : exist" + exist);
    Slog.d(TAG, "sdcard path:" + storageVolume.getPath());
    Slog.d(TAG, "getMaxFileSize:" + storageVolume.getMaxFileSize());

    final File file = storageVolume.getPathFile();
    Slog.d(TAG, "file get path :" + file.getPath());
    Slog.d(TAG, "file :" + file);

    final long fullBytes = storage.getStorageFullBytes(file);
    final long lowBytes = storage.getStorageLowBytes(file);
    Slog.d(TAG, "sdcard getPathFile fullBytes:" + fullBytes);
    Slog.d(TAG, "sdcard getPathFile lowBytes:" + lowBytes);

    // Send relevant broadcasts and show notifications based on any
    // recently noticed state transitions.
    final UUID uuid = storageVolume.getStorageUuid();
    final State state = findOrCreateState(uuid);
    final long totalBytes = file.getTotalSpace();
    final long usableBytes = file.getFreeSpace();

    Slog.d(TAG, "sdcard getPathFile totalBytes:" + totalBytes);
    Slog.d(TAG, "sdcard getPathFile usableBytes:" + usableBytes);

}
```

Is there a solution to correctly obtain capacity?

Comment: `Slog.d(TAG, "sdcard path:" + storageVolume.getPath());` Please tell path.

Comment: And use file.exists() and file.canRead() before you call file.getTotalSpace().

Comment: sdcard path:/storage/6F41-1111 ;
when I call file.exists() and file.canRead()，both return false, is it because of permission security issues in the framework ?

Comment: That is strange. That looks like a normal path and both should return true. Which Android version on used device?

Comment: What does second item returned by getExternalFilesDirs(null) look like?

Comment: It is indeed strange that this code can obtain capacity normally in setting app, but when it is put into the framework, there is a problem, the Android version of the device being used is T. 
I'm not sure if it's like what you said, but I obtained the path of the SD card through StorageManage, I am not very sure about its workflow either.